# Why is my input tag losing focus immediately after getting it?

Tags: javascript, html

By the design, menu container onblur event should be disabled when input gets focus and it should be enabled back when input loses focus (i.e. when user finishes input.

```
function pauseHiding(hiderId) {
    var hider = document.getElementById(hiderId);
    hider.onblur = null;
}

function resumeHiding(hiderId, timeout) {
    var hider = document.getElementById(hiderId);
    hider.onblur = "setTimeout(function(){hideMenu(hiderId);}, timeout);";
    hider.focus();
}
```

In fact, input's onfocus event fires normally, but it is followed immediately by onblur event. Moreover, onfocus erases menu container's onblur event, but input's onblur doesn't returns it back.
https://jsfiddle.net/2dxre6nz/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `showMenu()` function you have to remove `focus()` use

```
function showMenu(containerId) {
    var el = document.getElementById(containerId);
    var setVisible = function(element){
        if (element.tagName == 'A') element.style.display = 'inline';
        else
            if (element.tagName != 'SCRIPT' && element.tagName != 'STYLE') element.style.display = 'block';
        };
    iterateChildren(el, setVisible);
        //el.focus();
}
```

You set `onclick="showMenu('userbody')"` in your main div, so each click change your focus

Comment: At first click there is only `blur` event on input, and on second there is `blur` event on div

Comment: How can I avoid that two click blur? Tried to add `document.getElementsByName(senderName)[0].blur();` to input's onblur handler, but nothing seems to change.